# Hide/show a icon depending upon the location.search?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let us say i have a page http://www.abc.com/xyz.html and i am going to access this page in two ways

1. simple as it is
2. I will append some stuff to the url e.g. http://www.abc.com/xyz.html?nohome by just putting  the value ?nohome manually in the code.

Now i will add some javascript code something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
if (location.search=="?value=nohome") {
        // wanna hide a button in this current page
    }
    else {
       // just show the original page.
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your particular question/problem? How to hide an element? http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using jQuery to catch the DOM-ready event, I guess a jQuery solution to your problem would be fine, even though the question isn't tagged jQuery:

You can use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide and element:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if (location.search=="?value=nohome")
    {
        $("#idOfElementToHide").hide();
    }

    // Got rid of the else statement, since you didn't want to do anything on else
});
```

Comment: U know i was trying nearly same thing from last 2 hours and no results but u seems lucky to me :) thanks